# how to display selected options (drop down menu) in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

how to display the selected options below in jsp

```
<td width="75%" valign="center">
   Start Date : &nbsp;
   <input id="startDate" name="startDate" id = "startDate" type="text" size="20"><a href="javascript:NewCal('startDate','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="$
   Start Time :&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <select name="startTime" id = "startTime">
        <option value="0">10:00</option>
        <option value="1">11:00</option>
        <option value="2">12:00</option>
        <option value="3">13:00</option>
        <option value="4">14:00</option>
        <option value="5">15:00</option>
        <option value="6">16:00</option>
        <option value="7">17:00</option>
        <option value="8">18:00</option>
        <option value="9">19:00</option>
        <option value="10">20:00</option>
        <option value="11">21:00</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

i thought `request.getParameterValues` will be valuable but it shows only something like `value="something"` only but not the value between both of `options` tag.
Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is using [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (expression language). Request parameters are available as implicit objects in EL. `${param.startTime}` equals `request.getParameter("startTime")`.

If you need the option's text instead of the value it's best to create an `ArrayList` of `Strings` which you can use to generate the dropdown and to look up the value:

```
List<String> startTimeList = new ArrayList<String>();
startTimeList.add("10:00");
startTimeList.add("11:00");
request.setAttribute("startTimeList", startTimeList);
```

You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) ([`c:forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakm)) to generate the list using the [index](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) (see the [`varStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) attribute) as your option's `value`:

```
<c:forEach items="${startTimeList}" var="startTime" varStatus="status">
  <option value="${status.index}">${startTime}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

You can then use the `value` (index) to get an item from your list: `${startTimeList[param.startTime]}`.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a link to information on EL.

Comment: ok thanks. BTW, how can i use it on a single JSP file? So, i only have <% ---my codes --- %> then save it in name.jsp then i call later on my other .jsp file.

Comment: Best way is by using a MVC framework. You might want to check out JSF, Spring or Playframework.